# Vertex normals in the geometry shader using directx

Tags: shaders, directx, directx11, hlsl, geometry

I'm in directx 11 with the geometry shader.

Is is possible to calculate vertex normals? Just one like segment per vertex? In the geometry shader?

I did vertex normals per face, this is what I got,
[image]

My exercise in the book wants something like
[image]

Comment: Maybe it could be done with adjacency primitive topology, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Primitive_Adjacency

Comment: Are you asking how to compute averaged or smoothed vertex normals?

Answer (score 1):

Computing vertex normals is a complex process as you need to have all incident faces available, and the ability to "split verts" when needed. This is not really something well suited to the Geometry Shader. Face normals do fit well with Geometry Shader because you only care about the primitive itself.

Is there some reason you have to do this on the GPU?

The [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) library implements a number of different vertex normal calculations, but works on the CPU. In particular, see [ComputeNormals](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/wiki/ComputeNormals). Typically all your geometry data is conditioned at build time to include needed things like vertex normals, tangents or bi-tangents (if needed).

Here are some references as well:

- S Jin, R R Lewis, and D West; "A comparison of algorithms for vertex normal computation".
  [link](http://www.tricity.wsu.edu/~bobl/personal/mypubs/2003_vertnorm_tvc.pdf)
- Nelson Max, "Weights for Computing Vertex Normals from Facet Normals"
  [link](https://computing.llnl.gov/vis/images/pdf/max_jgt99.pdf)
- Max Wagner, "Generating Vertex Normals"
  [link](http://www.emeyex.com/site/tuts/VertexNormals.pdf)

Comment: I'd also add that vertex normals tend to stay the same, and as such, computing them at a shader level also wastes computational time.